# Login Automation with Powershell

Tags: powershell, configuration

Was wondering if anyone here has an idea to solve this issue I'm coming across. I'm not even sure if Powershell will be useable but any help/direction would be appreciated. I'm working on automating the configuration of a large number of laptops, and have solved most of the thing's I've come across after enough reading.

Where I'm running into issues, is that after the initial boot, the computer logs into the built into Administrator account, which runs a PS script that imports the default application associations, then generates a new local account, configures permissions for an SD card, etc. After all this is done, it restarts the computer. Once the computer is restarted, then I need to manually log into the local account, and run the next script.

Now realistically, the computer doesn't need to be restarted, so what I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to have a script run to switch the user from Admin to the local account, then after the initial windows "configuration" on the new account runs, runs the next script in line? Or will the script continue to run if you switch user?

Thanks for any assistance you can provide

Answer (score 0):

You can use the invoke-command as follows

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME  -ScriptBlock { [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name} -Credential domain\user
```

by the way, the line gives you the user to run this script

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```